# Is there an inverse of it_behaves_like in Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

Is there something to the effect of 'it_doesnt_behave_like' or 'group_will_fail_with(SomeError)'?  I don't see anything in the docs, but I feel like this would be desirable functionality.  E.g.

```
shared_examples_for "a foo doer for admin" do
  it "does this" do
   ...
  end

  it "does that" do
   ...
  end
end

context "when logged in as an admin" do
  let(:admin)   { FactoryGirl :admin }
  before(:each) { sign_in_as admin }

  it_behaves_like "a foo doer for admin"
end

context "when logged in as a user" do
  let(:user)    { FactoryGirl :user }
  before(:each) { sign_in_as user }

  # is there something like this?
  group_will_fail_with("a foo doer for admin", SomeError) / it_behaves_not_like "a foo maker" / etc.
end
```

If this is an anti-pattern or there is something wrong with my thinking all corrections are appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just write a shared example expects the negative outcome (`ìt_behaves_like 'a rejected user'`)? Or an shared example that expects to raise an error (`it_behaves_like 'a request raising an 403'`)?

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, and it works just fine.  It seems like this must be a common enough test for there to be a built in way to avoid the code duplication, since I'm sending the same request, only expecting a different response?

Comment: I would argue that a shared example (a list of expectations) is quite different   from expecting something to raise an error. I think it is worth it to write both cases - especially because RSpec uses different syntaxes to spec return values vs. expecting an error to be raised. But are you aware that you can pass parameters to shared examples (see: [docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples))? You just might want to pass in the expected outcome: `it_behaves_like 'action for admin', 'failed'` and handle the different cases in the shared examples?

Comment: @spickermann that's a very good point.  I also didn't know about the parameters with a shared example, that's a good tip and would probably do what I'm thinking.  However, the more I think about it, I agree that simply expecting a block of tests to fail the same way probably isn't the best way to do the test to begin with.

Comment: Are you just looking for the "raise_error" matcher?  http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-5/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher